# I am trying to make a Telegram Bot. But getting error, don't know how to get rid of it

Tags: python-telegram-bot

[thats a simple code and Cmd  output line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xykLz.jpg)
bot name - @ting_ting_bot

Answer (score 0):

Ok, instead of `telebot.Telebot` use `telebot.TeleBot`. Note that `B` in `TeleBot`.

In the docs of [pyTelegramBotApi's](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/) docs it is provided:

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN", parse_mode=None) # You can set parse_mode by default. HTML or MARKDOWN
```